# Issues getting SQL statement to select the items I want it to

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to send an email to users with the group level of 4 or 5. I have the group levels distinguished in my 'users' table. I'm trying to get the email and 'firstname' of the users with the 'group' level of 4 or 5. Then to use that email and first name to create variables with it and use it for my email.

Am I structuring my SQL statement incorrectly? I am not getting any errors.

The area where I am struggling with are these lines.

```
if($sql_email = "SELECT 'email' FROM 'users' WHERE 'group' = 4 AND 5") {

    $email = $con->query($sql_email);
} else {
    echo "Query not working right";
}

        $sql_name = "SELECT 'firstname' FROM 'users' WHERE 'group' = 4 AND 5";
            $admin_name = $con->query($sql_name);
```

More code to show how I am using it

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

 //User Request Email that goes to the commissioner and creator
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                        exit();
                }

                if($sql_email = "SELECT 'email' FROM 'users' WHERE 'group' = 4 AND 5") {

                $email = $con->query($sql_email);
                } else {
                    echo "Query not working right";
                }

                $sql_name = "SELECT 'firstname' FROM 'users' WHERE 'group' = 4 AND 5";
                $admin_name = $con->query($sql_name);

                $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                $username = $_POST['username'];


                $to = $email;
                $subject = 'There is a new user request to join the SFL';
                $message = '
                    <html>
                    <head>
                      <title>New SFL User Request</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Hi '.$admin_name.',</p><br>
                        <p>Thank you for wanting to join the!</p>

                          <p>Thank you,</p>
                          <p>Administration</p>
                    </body>
                    </html>
                          ';

                $from = "user-requests@example.com";
                $Bcc = "user-requests-confirm@example.com";

                // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

                // Additional headers
                $headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Bcc: '.$Bcc. "\r\n";

                // Send the email
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                }
```

UPDATE

```
$sql_email = "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `group` = 4 OR `group` = 5";

    $email = $con->query($sql_email);

if( ! $con->query($sql_email) )
    echo "Query not working right";

$sql_name = "SELECT `firstname` FROM `users` WHERE `group` = 4 OR `group` = 5";
$admin_name = $con->query($sql_name);
```

I get this error..
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /home4/db/public_html/example.com/register.php on line 219

Line 219 is this...

```
<p>Hi '.$admin_name.',</p><br>
```

Comment: Aside from the code, if you're ever gonna be querying user input into your database, don't use mysql queries. Use PDO and bind your variables as parameters. While mysqli is better than using the mysql() functions, PDO is more secure.

Comment: How exactly is PDO more secure than Mysqli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you execute a select query, you need to fetch records. I assume you need to send email to all users found.

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

$sql_email = "SELECT `email`, `firstname` FROM `users` WHERE `group` IN (4,5)";
$users = $con->query($sql_email);
if (($users) && ($users->num_rows > 0)){// Got any record?
    // output data of each row
    while($user = $users->fetch_assoc()){
        $to = $user['email'];
        $subject = 'There is a new user request to join the SFL';
        $message = '
            <html>
            <head>
              <title>New SFL User Request</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>Hi '.$user['firstname'].',</p><br>
                <p>Thank you for wanting to join the!</p>

                  <p>Thank you,</p>
                  <p>Administration</p>
            </body>
            </html>
                  ';

        $from = "user-requests@example.com";
        $Bcc = "user-requests-confirm@example.com";

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        // Additional headers
        $headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Bcc: '.$Bcc. "\r\n";

        // Send the email
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
}
else{
    echo "No User Found!";
}
```

You can learn more from here: [Select Data With MySQLi](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT anything FROM `users` WHERE `group` = 4 OR `group` = 5
```

Besides,

```
if($sql_email = "SELECT 'email' FROM 'users' WHERE 'group' = 4 AND 5")
```

is useless as the result will always be true.

You can say

```
if( ! $con->query($sql_email) )
    echo "Query not working right";
```

Comment: I updated my question. I changed my code to basically what you had and am getting an error saying I cannot convert my variable to string. Question regarding your answer though. Why `Select anything` , doesn't that defeat the purpose of getting the email and firstname fields?

Comment: I gave you a tip to fix your script not actual copy of that. change `anything` to email, firstname, ... I just wanted to say `group = 4 AND 5` is not true in this case.